# A simple question with sed and pipe with shell script

Tags: bash, sed, pipe

A sed and script problem needs to save

i want to write a script and do something like this
the whole task is write a shell script and convert parameters to the command used by sed ,Then call sed to print the specified line from stdin .

seq 1 100 | ./script.sh 1 9 34-35

and get the answer with :

1
9
34
35

below is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

str="sed -n -e '"

data=$(cat)
#echo "$data"

for arg in $@;do
 if [ `expr index $arg -` -eq 0 ]; then
   str="$str${arg}p;"
 else
   len=`expr length $arg`
   i=`expr index $arg -`
   i=`expr $i - 1`
   tmp1=`expr substr $arg 1 $i`
   str="$str${tmp1},"
   i=`expr $i + 2`
   tmp2=`expr substr $arg $i $len`
   str="$str${tmp2}p;"
 fi
done
str="$str'"
echo "$str"
`echo $data | $str`
#echo `$str`
~
```

and i got the error
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

what is the problem
and
how can i do this correct?

Comment: It's really not clear what this script should do. The immediate problem is that you can't usefully store a command in a string (see e.g. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) but this whole thing looks hopelessly tortured and should probably be rewritten as (I'm guessing) a one-liner in Awk. Generally, Bash scripts do not need `expr`, and you should avoid it because the built-in replacements are both more robust and more efficient as well as more versatile than `expr`.

Comment: Before asking for human assistance, try https://shellcheck.net/

Comment: How this code `data=$(cat)` suppose to work? Guess you need https://www.shellcheck.net

Comment: @tripleee thanks for replying this . Since I'm a freshman in college our professor asking us to doing this in a shell script. the whole task is write a shell script and convert parameters to the command used by sed ,Then call sed to print the specified line from stdin . And what i do above is refer to professor's old code

Comment: `./script.sh()( local c; for a; do if ! [[ $a =~ ^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?$ ]]; then echo bad args 1>&2; exit 1; fi; c=$c${a/-/,}p$'\n'; done; echo $(sed -n "$c") )`

Comment: Maybe relay our feedback to your professor, though I imagine they might have a point they are trying to get across with this ghastly example. We still can't guess what the code should do.

Comment: @Ivan, `$(cat)` is one way to read everything in standard input into a variable.  See [What's wrong with var=$(</dev/stdin) to read stdin into a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/716438/264812).

Comment: Please, _please_ get our feedback to your professor. The world is a worse place because people who don't understand [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050); the practices shown in that code sample don't belong anywhere near a teaching resource.

Comment: BTW, to make some of the advice you've already been given more concrete, `i=$((i - 1))` is the faster, built-in, modern (meaning standard-mandated ever since POSIX.2 was published in the early 90s) equivalent to `i=$(expr "$i" - 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code builds a string.

With arguments `1` `9` `34-35`, you will get:
`sed -n -e '1p;9p;34,35p;'`

You call:

```
`echo $data | $str`
```

This becomes two commands piped together:

- `echo` with arguments: `1` `2` `3` `4` `5` `6` `7` `8` `9` `10` `11` `12` `13` `14` `15` `16` `17` `18` `19` `20` `21` `22` `23` `24` `25` `26` `27` `28` `29` `30` `31` `32` `33` `34` `35` `36` `37` `38` `39` `40` `41` `42` `43` `44` `45` `46` `47` `48` `49` `50` `51` `52` `53` `54` `55` `56` `57` `58` `59` `60` `61` `62` `63` `64` `65` `66` `67` `68` `69` `70` `71` `72` `73` `74` `75` `76` `77` `78` `79` `80` `81` `82` `83` `84` `85` `86` `87` `88` `89` `90` `91` `92` `93` `94` `95` `96` `97` `98` `99` `100`
- `sed` with arguments: `-n` `-e` `'1p;9p;34,35p;'`

Note that the shell does no further manipulation of the words. In particular, quote-stripping has already happened (there were none before expansion).

So sed receives a script argument starting literally with `'`.

`'` is not a valid sed command, so the error is printed.

Note that `$data` should have been quoted, otherwise the shell will strip out the newlines as shown above, and `echo` when run will output only a single line.

Note also that if the sed had succeeded, the backticks will cause the shell to try to run its output as a new command. This seems very unlikely to be what you intended.

To fix your code, it would make more sense to avoid confusion by separating commands and arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash

str=

data=$(cat)
#echo "$data"

for arg in $@;do
 if [ `expr index $arg -` -eq 0 ]; then
   str="$str${arg}p;"
 else
   len=`expr length $arg`
   i=`expr index $arg -`
   i=`expr $i - 1`
   tmp1=`expr substr $arg 1 $i`
   str="$str${tmp1},"
   i=`expr $i + 2`
   tmp2=`expr substr $arg $i $len`
   str="$str${tmp2}p;"
 fi
done
echo `echo "$data" | sed -n -e "$str"`
```

And you can simplify / modernise to:

```
#!/bin/bash

str=

for arg; do
 if [ $(expr index $arg -) -eq 0 ]; then
   str="$str${arg}p;"
 else
   len=$(expr length $arg)
   i=$(expr index $arg -)
   i=$(expr $i - 1)
   tmp1=$(expr substr $arg 1 $i)
   str="$str${tmp1},"
   i=$(expr $i + 2)
   tmp2=$(expr substr $arg $i $len)
   str="$str${tmp2}p;"
 fi
done

# this command will already read from stdin, so no need to buffer the data
echo $(sed -n -e "$str")
```

`expr` is rather tedious to use.
Making use of bash's built-in functionality you can simplify much further:

```
#!/bin/bash

str=

for arg; do
    str=$str${arg/-/,}"p;"
done

echo $(sed -n "$str") # output is combined into single line
                      # for separate lines, just do: sed -n "$str"
```

Or with argument validation:

```
#!/bin/bash

str=

for arg; do
    if ! [[ $arg =~ ^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?$ ]]; then
        echo bad args 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi
    str=$str${arg/-/,}"p;"
done

echo $(sed -n "$str")
```

Any of these versions produce the sample output from the question.

Comment: Note that the problem is underspecified. For example, if arguments passed were `1` `1` `1` should the first line of input be displayed three times? What is would be the meaning of `37-34`? etc

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU bash and sed):

```
f(){ <<<"$@" sed 'y/-/,/;s/\S\+/&=\n/g'; }
seq 100 | sed -nf <(f 1 9 34-35) | paste -sd' '
```

Create a function `f` that parse the required arguments and produces a sed script to output the required line numbers of an input file.

Pipe the file (or provide a filename) and using a sed invocation that takes the sed commands from a process substitution and kills implicit printing to ouput those line numbers to another pipe that serially pastes the results separated by a space.

The command could be invoked either as a `cat` command or an input file.

```
 cat file | sed -nf <(f 1 9 34-35) | paste -sd' '
```

or:

```
sed -nf <(f 1 9 34-35) file | paste -sd' '
```

The process may be turned into a one liner:

```
sed -nf <(<<<'1 9 34-45' sed 'y/-/,/;s/\S\+/&=;/g') file | paste -sd' '
```